# Efficient way to create lists/collections of pairs: numeric enum key and objects in TypeScript/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

What would be the simplest list of pairs: `{enum(numeric) - object}` in TypeScript/JavaScript?

Suppose we have this example code:

```
// interface for some objects
export interface ObjI {
  num: number;
  str: string;
}

// some objects
export const objA: ObjI = {
  num: 10000,
  str: "AAAA",
};
export const objA1: ObjI = {
  num: 100001,
  str: "AAA1",
};
export const objB: ObjI = {
  num: 200000,
  str: "BBB",
};

export const objB2: ObjI = {
  num: 200000,
  str: "BBB",
};
export const objC: ObjI = {
  num: 333,
  str: "CCC",
};

// enum of indexes - normally larger values
enum objEnum {
  A = 10,
  A1 = 11,
  A2 = 12,
  B = 20,
  B8 = 28,
  C = 30,
  C7 = 37,
  C9 = 39,
}

// output tests
export class TestValues {
  run() {
    const ar: ObjI[] = [];
    ar[objEnum.A2] = objA;
    ar[objEnum.B8] = objB;
    ar[objEnum.C9] = objC;

    let ix: number;

    console.log("-----");

    // This returns:
    //  0 " val: " "AAAA"
    //  1 " val: " "BBB"
    //  2 " val: " "CCC"
    ix = 0;
    ar.forEach((o) => console.log(ix++, " val: ", o.str));

    console.log("-----");

    // This returns:
    //  0 - 39 lines - 40 elements
    ix = 0;
    for (let o of ar) {
      console.log(ix++, " val: ", o ? o.str : "-");
    }

    console.log("-----");
    // This returns:
    //  0, 1, 2
    ix = 0;
    for (let o in ar) {
      // THIS CANNOT BE USED - error:
      // Property 'str' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)
      //console.log(ix++, ' val: ', o.str);
      console.log(ix++);
    }
  }
}
```

Questions:

It appears that in the array '`ar[39] = xxx`' TypeScript generates in memory 40 elements from 0 - 39.

Is that true? If so, that would be a waste or resources considering we only add 3 elements and array would not be the right type to apply.

What would be the most efficient way to create lists of various groups of `{number - object}` pairs, having a given numeric index that may not be in sequence of 1 and be of higher value numbers e.g. 1001, 1202, 1307, etc. - as in the example array '`ar[]`' ?

Comment: It's not TS, it's just how JS works, try it in console:
 `
const ar = [];
ar[39] == `xxx`;
//  [empty × 39, 'xxx']
`
An efficient way would be to use an object:
obj[1001] = 'xxx', and later to use Object.keys(obj) to loop through the values, or access them directly as obj[key]

Answer (score 1):

> It appears that in the array 'ar[39] = xxx' TypeScript generates in memory 40 elements from 0 - 39. Is that true?

Nope.

```js
const arr = []
arr[39] = 'hello'
console.log(Object.keys(arr)) // [39]
```

Note that `"39"` is the only key that this array has. How this is implemented under the hood could be somewhat unclear. Worst case scenario, it stores the integers up until the largest index as keys, and `undefined` as the value, which won't consume much memory at all.

---

> What would be the most efficient way to create lists of various groups of {number - object} pairs?

That said, if you are mapping an integer key to a value, you probably want either a plain object, or a `Map`. Arrays are, typically, for lists of data where the order only matter in a relative sense (item 0 should appear before item 1). But if you want to fetch each item by some unique key, an array is usually not what you want.

As a map:

```
const map: Map<number, ObjI> = new Map();

map.set(objEnum.A2, objA);
map.set(objEnum.B8, objB);
map.set(objEnum.C9, objC);

for (const [k, v] of map) {
  console.log(k, v)
}

// "12",  { "num": 10000, "str": "AAAA" } 
// "28",  { "num": 200000, "str": "BBB" } 
// "39",  { "num": 333, "str": "CCC" }
```

Or a plain object with an index signature would also work:

```
const obj: { [key: number] : ObjI } = {};
obj[objEnum.A2] = objA;
obj[objEnum.B8] = objB;
obj[objEnum.C9] = objC;

for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  console.log(k, v)
}

// "12",  { "num": 10000, "str": "AAAA" } 
// "28",  { "num": 200000, "str": "BBB" } 
// "39",  { "num": 333, "str": "CCC" }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#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-WA+35YZQas0lyFanOgDRD1vtzvdjVBd4zmdBLXZlurUA-QWiACyyEFAB4bQgS7Z2AA+BqQWAAd1Am8F2sXbtXPrwsGg9YjqfxJaDC6HD6fL5Tvoxp+FDVN+oa-s+r7kJGabcsM6zfkOeagAWy7FqWNwrluTZDnqlRth2XY9n2UKDqGGh8BoI5npecqKEqvywng2o+mqmpakAA)

Comment: Logical response. Only the "Worst case scenario..." in array ... would still be some waste if the index numbers were very high. But I would think, the design is smarter than that. Still, the plain object appears to be the answer here. Perhaps Map or Record types, but there would be a small overhead of the underlying class